# Adding your own custom macros like "sout"in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I really like to be able to type sout and get System.out.println. In fact, I like it so much that I want to add more of these. For example, fb could be final boolean.

How do I add that?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html

Comment: Have you read the related documentation? https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/live-templates.html

Comment: I did not realize that it was called "templates". What a horrible naming.

Comment: Better than "macro", because they _are_ templates. :P

Comment: Also, did not work: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m7hyvfzljecft4d/Screenshot%202015-06-29%2013.26.20.png?dl=0

Comment: @ChristianJonassen It works ... if you define the context.

Comment: @Tom nope. https://www.dropbox.com/s/cb5h7fnrhttu6js/Screenshot%202015-06-29%2013.31.17.png?dl=0 and, well, https://www.dropbox.com/s/zfnkz1d17igvk38/Screenshot%202015-06-29%2013.31.33.png?dl=0 ...

Comment: oh, I see now what you mean. the context UNDER the text field. sorry. feel free to make an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like said in the comments, these macros are called ["Live Templates"](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/live-templates.html).

To create one:

- open the settings menu
- select the "Live Templates" entry in the left menu
- select the category where you like to create your new template
- press the "+" button on the right hand side of the settings menu window
- add the abbreviation, "fb" in your case
- add a description
- ... and then the text:

  ```
    final boolean
  ```

  (`$END$` can be omitted here)
- Now select the *context* (link is beneath the text field) where this template will be used and recognized by IDEA

  I've used the contexts Java *Statement*, *Expression*, *Declaration* and *Other* (but "Other" isn't shown in the list of contexts).

It could like this:
[image: live template example]

To use it write `fb` on the appropriate place and either wait until IDEA suggests to use the template or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> to activate the auto complete, it should create:

```
final boolean
```

You may find some more information about creating and editing live templates on the official help page: [Creating and Editing Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html)